# MSBuild: Problems specifying platform for child builds

Tags: msbuild

Is it possible to specify the target platform (x64, x86) when building a project?

I have a build task that looks as follows:

```
<MSBuild Projects="%(AgentProjectFiles.FullPath)" Properties="Architecture=x86;Configuration=$(Configuration);Optimize=$(Optimize);Platform=$(Platform);OutputPath=$(OutputDirectory)\Agent\;ReferencePath=$(ReferencePath);DebugSymbols=$(DebugSymbols);DebugType=none;" />
```

As you can probably tell, I've thrown everything possible I have seen online into the Properties attribute in the hope that it will work. You will notice that for the Architecture property I've set it to be x86 explicitly. the $(Platform) is also set to x86. I've tried a number of permutations, without success.

Unfortunately, it seems that no matter what gets put into these properties, my class libraries are x86, but my executables are x64.

I thought perhaps the problem could be that the build properties specified in the project file itself were causing MSBuild to ignore the ones I pass through from MSBuild, but after changing these to x86, I still have the same problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the declaration of the **AgentProjectFiles** item are you defining the **Properties** metadata. So does it look like:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <AgentProjectFiles Include="something.proj">
        <Properties>SOME VALUES HERE</Properties>
    </AgentProjectFiles>
</ItemGroup>
```

If you have defined that then the properties passed into the Properties attribute of the [MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7f65y0d.aspx) are ignored. I've bloged about this [MSBuild: Properties and AdditionalProperties Known Metadata](http://sedodream.com/2009/04/29/MSBuildPropertiesAndAdditionalPropertiesKnownMetadata.aspx).

Sayed Ibrahim Hashimi

My Book: [Inside the Microsoft Build Engine : Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Comment: THANK YOU!!!

(excuse the caps, but ive been hitting my head against the wall for a few hours with this.)

I changed my ItemGroup to define the properties as you have above, and my assemblies are now being created for the correct platform.

Comment: I don't really believe this is the truth. Thank you Sayed.