# Targeting x86 & x64 assemblies from the same VS2012 project; references

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, build, x86, 64-bit

I have a Visual Studio 2012 .Net project for which I would like to create both 32-bit (x86) and 64-bit (x64) using the same solution and project, just different configurations.

I already created the four different configuration/builds (Debug, Release, Debug64, and Release64). I went to the project properties and set in the build tab the proper processor and build location.

My problem deals in how to handle the references.

For instance, I am using ChilkatDotNet45, which ships with both 32-bit and 64-bit versions. The same DLL name, not that that matters. The x86 build requires the 32-bit version of my 3rd party assemblies, such as those from Chilkat, and the x64-bit version requires the 64-bit versions of those same assemblies.

I tried adding both DLL assemblies to the references, but VS2012 refused to allow the second one saying that the assembly already exists.

I did read the other stackoverflow posting that talks a bit about targeting both processor versions, but I did not see, at least clearly, how to handle the references.
[Targeting both 32bit and 64bit with Visual Studio in same solution/project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145803/targeting-both-32bit-and-64bit-with-visual-studio-in-same-solution-project)

I have several 3rd party assemblies that ship with 32-bit and 64-bit. How do I handle the references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I combined the responses in

[Conditionally use 32/64 bit reference when building in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832552/conditionally-use-32-64-bit-reference-when-building-in-visual-studio)

to find the solution. I had to use platform as the conditional test.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the project type to `AnyCPU`

Comment: I realize that option, but I do not see how that addresses the references issue. Also, I would like to create specific builds that target 32-bit and 64-bit. Think of the SQLite.Net distributions or any of the others that exist. I want to do the same.

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442435/one-project-with-multiple-build-configurations-in-vs2010

Comment: The builds go into different folders already. That is not my current problem. The References section is. My current folders are "x86/Debug, x86/Release, x64/Debug, and x64/Release). Each build/configuration ties to the appropriate processor. I have configurations Debug/Release/Debug64/Release64.